# Rest api call from angular app thowing errors to indeed api

Tags: javascript, angularjs, rest, api

Below is a angular service I created to return search results from Indeed job search api:

```
(function() {
    "use strict";

    angular
        .module("career.resources")
        .factory("JobSearchService", ["$http", jobsearchService]);

        function jobsearchService($http) {
             return{
                  getSearchResults: getSearchResults
             };

             function getSearchResults(publisherKey,keywords,location,jobType,limit) {
                 return $http.get("http://api.indeed.com/ads/apisearch?", {params: {
                    "publisher": publisherKey,
                    "v": "2",
                    "format": "json",
                    "callback": "JSON_CALLBACK",
                    "q": keywords,
                    "l": location,
                    "sort": "",
                    "radius": "",
                    "st": "",
                    "jt": jobType,
                    "start": "0",
                    "limit": limit,
                    "fromage": "",
                    "highlight": "1",
                    "filter": "1",
                    "userip": "1.2.3.4"
                }});
             }
         }
}());
```

When ever this call http request is made i get the following error:

**XMLHttpRequest cannot load (url). No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resoure. Origin 'http://localhost:62510' is therefore not allowed access**

Is there a way to bypass this, since I have a api key, to get back data?

I've also unsuccessfully attempted this via a $http.jsonp call [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40311936/http-jsonp-call-from-angular-app-returns-errors)

**UPDATED**
I've tried to accomplish this via $.ajax call also but this happens outside the scope of angular and the data never gets saved to the scope variable.

Comment: Is that supposed to be a publicly available GET API?

Comment: The publisherKey/api key is probably mapped to your hostname. You will probably need to update your host file on your local dev environment with something like 127.0.0.1 localhost.mydomain.com.

Comment: @deceze no but I have a publisher key that gives me access

Comment: @Hoyen would I then need to pass that address as my "userid"?

Comment: @aqwright31 No. In your browser instead of http://localhost:62510 you would use http://localhost.mydomain.com:62510

Comment: I don't see a userid, but only a userip.  Since you have the publisher key, they won't need the userid per se.

`userip The IP number of the end-user to whom the job results will be displayed. This field is required.`

Comment: I'm sorry I meant userip